# Alignement with marginpar

Tags: vertical-alignment

I am using marginpar to write something in the margin and then write some other things just next to that. However, the lines do not match properly and there is a slight difference (see print screen). Can anyone help me to adjust the text in order to have a perfect matching between the rows? I think it has to do with the "y" that put everything down

Thanks in advance

[image]

```
% PACKAGES
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[a4paper, 10 pt, oneside, final]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=4.1cm, right=0.75cm, top=0.5cm, bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{marvosym}

% Title format
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{} [{\color{coolblack}}\vskip-\topskip\rule{\linewidth}{0.8pt}]
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{0ex plus 0ex minus 0ex}{0ex plus 0ex}



% Title line color
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{coolblack}{RGB}{58, 53, 61}

% Left margin
\reversemarginpar
\marginparwidth 82pt




% DOCUMENT
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

% Command label item
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\raise .5ex\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}
\newcommand{\mymarginnote}[1]{\marginpar{\normalsize\textcolor{black}{#1}}}




% Personal informations and picture
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{00mm}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[scale=0.12]{cv_picture.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure} 
\noindent \mymarginnote{\fontsize{10.5}{12}\textbf{Arnaud Money}}\

\noindent  Born on the 21th of March  1887 \

\mymarginnote{Route 17 \\ Alabama \\ USA\\ \Telefon \thinspace +4167899724 } 

\noindent Single \

\noindent US nationality\

\noindent  \Letter \thinspace branchsmith@gmail.com
```

Comment: This just looks like an abuse of `\marginpar` (it is also not clear why you are ending lines with `\`). Have you thought about using a table or some other technique more suitable for doing horizontal alignment?

Comment: Yes, but the thing is I want to write some stuff in the margin and some other stuff in the body part. Do you see my problem?

Comment: It is just a question of what you call a margin. It looks like you want 2 (maybe 3) columns, with one of the columns really narrow and a very small margin.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try to increase my margin to see if it helps. :)

Comment: The margin note should be attached to the text you want it to align with, you have placed it at the end of the paragraph attached to nothing which is why it is not aligned. But the `\ ` at the ends of the lines are wrong, and all the `\noindent` are weird.

Comment: Thanks for your support, I am new in latex as well. May you provide an example how you would write in correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure that marginpar is really the right markup here but having got that far you can do:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10 pt, oneside, final]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=4.1cm, right=0.75cm, top=0.5cm, bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{soul}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{marvosym}

% Title format
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{} [{\color{coolblack}}\vskip-\topskip\rule{\linewidth}{0.8pt}]
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{0ex plus 0ex minus 0ex}{0ex plus 0ex}



% Title line color
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{coolblack}{RGB}{58, 53, 61}

% Left margin
\reversemarginpar
\marginparwidth 84pt




% DOCUMENT
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

% Command label item
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\raise .5ex\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}
\newcommand{\mymarginnote}[1]{\leavevmode
\marginpar{\normalsize\textcolor{black}{#1}}%
\ignorespaces}


\setlength\parindent{0pt}

% Personal informations and picture
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{00mm}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[scale=0.12]{cv_picture.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure} 

\mymarginnote{\smash{\fontsize{10.5}{12}\textbf{Arnaud Money}}}
\mbox{}

\mymarginnote{Route 17 \\ Alabama \\ USA\\ \Telefon \thinspace +4167899724 } 
Born on the 21th of March  1887

Single

US nationality

\Letter \thinspace branchsmith@gmail.com

\end{document}
```

Comment: it's so perfect:) thanks a lot for your help, have a nice day